# How do I to Delete objects in different indexes of one NSArray? IOS

Tags: ios, nsarray

Well, guys.

I have a problem here, when I try to delete objects at different indexes of one `NSMutableArray`. 
 I know how init one `NSArray` of `NSIndexPath` using method `[_tableFavoritos indexPathsForSelectedRows]`, but I don't know how make a `NSIndexSet` from this `NSArray`.

I want to use the method

```
[arrayFavoritos removeObjectsAtIndexes : (here my NSIndexSet) ];
```

To solve this.

Or if someone know another way, be welcome.

Thanks...

```
NSArray *indexesArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[_tableFavoritos indexPathsForSelectedRows]];

[arrayFavoritos removeObjectsAtIndexes:];

[_tableFavoritos deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[_tableFavoritos indexPathsForSelectedRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[_tableFavoritos reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
NSArray *indexesArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[_tableFavoritos indexPathsForSelectedRows]];

NSMutableIndexSet *indexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet new];
[indexesArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSIndexPath *indexPath, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [indexSet addIndex:indexPath.row];
}];

[arrayFavoritos removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexSet];

[_tableFavoritos deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[_tableFavoritos indexPathsForSelectedRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

[_tableFavoritos reloadData];
```